# Плавное увеличение/ уменьшение границ

Tags: css, веб-дизайн

Как сделать, чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана, отступы справа и слева постепенно становились меньше, как на этом сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*[Ссылка на сайт](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2457.html)*

Comment: с помощью media queries, например

Comment: Там простой `margin: auto`

Answer (score 2):

Делается такое с помощью обычного `margin`:

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Это наша строка. Она делает одинаковые отступы слева и справа */
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Это я знаю. Но спрашиваю --- как сделать чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана эти отступы тоже уменьшались, если я задаю ширину блока в процентах? То есть при уменьшении экрана блок должен увеличиваться.

Comment: @Владимир, что значит при уменьшении экрана?

Comment: К примеру: на телефоне блок во весь экран, а на компьютере только на половину. Ну я уже разобрался, спасибо!! Нужно мин. ширину окна поставить на пример: 1000px и ширину блока 1000px, а отступы --- как вы сказали.